# GCM Listener after force close

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

A few days ago I added GCM to my project. It is working well, but after exit app and next -> 'force close' -> disable wifi and then start app again I am not receiving any response. 
How Can I disable receiving messages till app restart or
how to set GCM to resending messages till app restart?

Update:
I got last message after rebuild project, so it could be some problem with enable receiver at app launch.

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the notifications by un-registering from  [GCM](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#public-methods) (InstanceID.deleteToken() or InstanceID.deleteInstanceID()).This should stop messages from arriving to your app on that device until you register to GCM again.

Or, if you want your app to keep receiving the messages but stop showing them to the user, you can store a  [flag](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) in shared preferences which indicates if GCM is enabled. Then the code that handles incoming GCM messages will check this flag to decide what to do with the message.

Comment: I am sending some messages from server and I need to show them to the user. After 'force closed' and run it again the app should show the messages from the queue.
If I delete token the server will propably not able to send message to that token.
The flag is unnecessary.